# Zabbix Permission denied for read log from item of teample

Tags: permissions, zabbix

**Error:
Value of type "string" is not suitable for value type "Numeric (float)". Value "tail: cannot open '/home/user/mc/plugins/Skript/logs/tps.log' for reading: Permission denied"**

#groups zabbix

```
zabbix : user minecraft
user permissions of folder /home/user/*  "user" in group "minecraft" to
```

#ls -l

```
total 116
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zabbix minecraft 41976 сен 17 05:33 online.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zabbix minecraft 65070 сен 17 05:33 tps.log
```

#groups zabbix

```
zabbix : minecraft
```

#sudo -u zabbix tail /home/user/mc/plugins/Skript/logs/online.log

```
[17.09.2023, 05:31] 0
[17.09.2023, 05:32] 0
[17.09.2023, 05:32] 0
[17.09.2023, 05:33] 0
```

Ok i try get 777

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 zabbix minecraft 42284 сен 17 05:40 online.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 zabbix minecraft 65546 сен 17 05:40 tps.log

Same error
```

**WHY?**
[error image from gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfaqT.png)